# Dropdown filter in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a project for one of my subjects in college, consisting of, doing a dropdown list filter in pure javascript, to filter a grid of images in html/css. What is causing me problems is that this filter needs to work with 3 dropdowns list simultaneously. For example, if I choose nature and people they need to give me those two grids of images, and when i select category, all the images need to appear. If you guys can help me, i would be grateful.

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById("category1");


elemento.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var opcao = elemento.options[elemento.selectedIndex].text;

  var fotos = document.getElementsByClassName("photo");

  for (var i = 0; i < fotos.length; ++i) {
    if (!fotos[i].classList.contains(opcao)) {
      fotos[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      fotos[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <select id="category1">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
  <select id="category2">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
  <select id="category3">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo nature people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=1);"></div>

  <div class="photo landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=2);"></div>

  <div class="photo nature" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=3);"></div>

  <div class="photo people landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=4);"></div>

  <div class="photo people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=5);"></div>


  <div class="photo nature landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=6);"></div>

  <div class="photo people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=7);"></div>

  <div class="photo natureza landscapes people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=8);"></div>

  <div class="photo natureza landscapes people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=9);"></div>

  <div class="photo nature people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=10);"></div>

  <div class="photo landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=11);"></div>

  <div class="photo landscapes nature" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=12);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how do I make the filter to work simultaneously with the three dropdown lists. I've tried with this javascript code but it is not working. This photos are just for testing if the filter is working, they are not the real ones!

Comment: We could help you more easily if you would provide a complete and minimal example of your code to the point where you can't go on by yourself. In this case you have to add the (important!) CSS as well and make a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) out of it.

Comment: Is your question answered? Please provide feedback.

Comment: Yes, my question was answered, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my first attempt. If you need any explanations, feel free to ask in the comments.

```js
let selectedFilters = [];
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.photo')];
const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.filter select')];

for (const filter of filters) {
  filter.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    selectedFilters = filters.map(filter => filter.value).filter(Boolean);
    console.log(selectedFilters);
    for (const image of images) {
      image.classList[selectedFilters.some(filter => image.classList.contains(filter)) 
        ? 'add'
        : 'remove']('visible');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.photo {
  color: #fff;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-size: cover;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
}

.visible {
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <select id="category1">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
  <select id="category2">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
  <select id="category3">
    <option value="">category</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="nature">nature</option>
    <option value="landscapes">landscapes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo nature people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=1);">photo nature people</div>
  <div class="photo landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=2);">photo landscapes</div>
  <div class="photo nature" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=3);">photo nature</div>
  <div class="photo people landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=4);">photo people landscapes</div>
  <div class="photo people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=5);">photo people</div>
  <div class="photo nature landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=6);">photo nature landscapes</div>
  <div class="photo people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=7);">photo people</div>
  <div class="photo nature landscapes people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=8);">photo nature landscapes people</div>
  <div class="photo nature landscapes people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=9);">photo nature landscapes people</div>
  <div class="photo nature people" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=10);">photo nature people</div>
  <div class="photo landscapes" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=11);">photo landscapes</div>
  <div class="photo landscapes nature" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=12);">photo landscapes nature</div>
</div>
```